# Script SQL para criar mascara

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com um banco de dados de um cliente que com alguns dados sem mascara para uso no meu sistema que é o campo `NCM`;

O mesmo possui 8 dígitos ( ex.: 0000.00.00), Porem o mesmo no meu sistema esta sem mascara "00000000" eu preciso simplesmente colocar os pontos 4,2,2 porem não estou conseguindo montar um Update para fazer isso.

Usando este `select` eu consigo Visualizar o mesmo com as Mascaras :

```
select codigo,substring(d.classificacao_fiscal from 1 for 4)||'.'||
       substring(d.classificacao_fiscal from 5 for 2)||'.'||
       substring(d.classificacao_fiscal from 7 for 2) as classificacao_fiscal

from c000025 d
```

Porem Não consigo gerar um Update para atualizar os dados em questão;

Lembrando que o Campo `NCM`(Varchar 20) esta com o nome `Classificacao_fiscal` e o Nome da tabela é `c000025`;

Comment: Tanto faz pro SQL Server ou MySQL?

Comment: @GuilhermeNeitzelMachado: Como está declarada a coluna NCM?

Comment: a COLUNA Ncm esta definida como "Classificacao_fiscal" e a tabela com o nome "c000025"

Comment: @rray o script em questao seria para o SQL

Comment: O banco de dados aparenta em ordem. Caracteres de formatação normalmente não devem ser armazenados, e sim colocados na exibição.

Comment: Não formate dados no ambiente de banco de dados. É uma péssima prática, cria processamento no banco sem necessidade. Formatar dados não é de responsabilidade do banco. Deixa o sistema mais dificil de dar manutenção. Faça na camada de aplicação, ela foi feita para isso. Fará mais fácil, mais rápido, é testável, e vc terá mais recursos. São meus 50 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Partindo do principio de que você está utilizando SQL Server, de que todos os registros possuem 8 dígitos e que seu campo NCM é do tipo VARCHAR:

```
UPDATE TMP SET CODIGO = LEFT(CODIGO, 4) + '.' + SUBSTRING(CODIGO, 5, 2) + '.' + RIGHT(CODIGO, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja esse [***link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546428/apply-a-mask-to-format-a-string-in-sql-server-query-view), acredito que essa função faça exatamente o que precisa.

Abaixo é função citei no link.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_FormatUsingMask 
(    
    @input nvarchar(1000),
    @mask nvarchar(1000)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @result nvarchar(1000) = ''
    DECLARE @inputPos int = 1
    DECLARE @maskPos int = 1
    DECLARE @maskSign char(1) = ''

    WHILE @maskPos <= Len(@mask)
    BEGIN
        set @maskSign = substring(@mask, @maskPos, 1)

        IF @maskSign = '#'
        BEGIN
            set @result = @result + substring(@input, @inputPos, 1)
            set @inputPos += 1
            set @maskPos += 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            set @result = @result + @maskSign
            set @maskPos += 1
        END
    END
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @result

END;
```

Como chamar a função:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fx_FormatUsingMask]('00000000', '####.##.##')
```

Answer (score 0):

É possível chegar ao resultado com `stuff`.

```
update [tabela] set [coluna] = stuff(stuff([coluna],5,0,'.'),8,0,'.')
```

Em funcionamento aqui: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cce78/1/0)